# Using HtmlHelper for inner Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have such a Model structure for one of my Asp.net MVC views:

```
public class MyModel{
   public AnotherModel1 Prop1 {get;set;}
   public AnotherModel2 Prop2 {get;set;}
}
public class AnotherModel1{
   public InnerModel InnerProp1 {get;set;}
   public InnerModel InnerProp2 {get;set;}
   public InnerModel InnerProp3 {get;set;}
}
public class AnotherModel2{
   public InnerModel InnerProp1 {get;set;}
   public InnerModel InnerProp2 {get;set;}
}
public class InnerModel {
   public string Input {get;set;}
}
```

It means, MyModel is general model to pass to View. Some other models AnotherModel1, AnotherModel2 whose contain InnerModel as properties.

I want to create a helper function that will know how to render InnerModel.
Then in my page View I want to have an ability to write something like
@RenderInnerModel(m => m.Prop1.InnerProp1)

The problem is, I have no idea how to pass htmlhelper into my function to have ability to use @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Input) inside my helper.

While the problem could be solved by using partial views per InnerModel, I want to have parameterized helper function and don't want to mess up with complex models for partials e.g. using Tuple etc.

---

**EDIT**

While EditorFor seems to be almost what I want, I still want to understand is it possible to have something like

```
var modelHelper = new HtmlHelper<InnerModel>(ViewContext, this);
```

but in context of MyModel? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need custom editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller:

```
  public class AnotherModel
  {
     public InnerModel InnerProp1 { get; set; }
     public InnerModel InnerProp2 { get; set; }
  }
  public class InnerModel
  {
     public string Input { get; set; }
  }

  public class EditorExampleController : Controller
  {
     //
     // GET: /EditorExample/

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        AnotherModel model = new AnotherModel();
        model.InnerProp1 = new InnerModel { Input = "test 1" };
        model.InnerProp2 = new InnerModel { Input = "test 2" };
        return View(model);
     }
  }
```

your view:

```
  @model MVCApp.Controllers.AnotherModel
  <h2>Editor template</h2>
  @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.InnerProp1)
  @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.InnerProp2)
```

on "shared" folder in "Views" create a new folder call "EditorTemplates", then add a partial view "InnerModel.cshtml" :

```
  @model MVCApp.Controllers.InnerModel

  @if (Model.Input == "test 2")
  {
     <h4>@Model.Input</h4>
  }
  else
  {
     <h2>@Model.Input</h2>
  }
```

This is a simple implementation, if you want I can post a Custom HtmlHelper

Comment: Good answer, Also note that EditorFor can be parameterised with template name, incase there are multiple views for a given model in EditorTemplates.

Comment: @lucas-roselli yeah, EditorFor is a good catch but I want it be parameterized.
I see that I can have some fake property inside InnerModel and use it as parameter but this is not so pretty.
Could you, please, advise? Custom HtmlHelper can be helpful, thanks!

Comment: @drunkcamel alright, I completely understand, could you just give me a real example of you want, then I can make a more specific response

Comment: @lucas-roselli ok, let's say, I have InnerModel.Input to be represented by Html.DropdownListFor control and I want to pass possible select items and they are different per model.